# Invoking Groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures

If I define a closure in Groovy

```
def c = {println "foo"}
```

I can invoke it using either

```
c()
```

or

```
c.call()
```

AFAIK, these two are identical. However, I recently discovered a third way

```
c.doCall()
```

Are there any differences between `call()` and `doCall()`

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 16):

The doCall method is what gets invoked when you call c() or c.call().

I found an example that claimed it's used to call the closure from inside itself, but that seems to work with call() too.

The [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) says you need to provide a doCall() method to specify the parameters in order to call the closure in the short form (without explicitly using call()).  But I don't know how exactly they expect that to work.

[Here's an explanation of call vs. doCall.](http://marc.info/?l=groovy-dev&m=113684784008467&w=2)

Comment: Can you explain (maybe give an example) of what you mean by

"you need to provide a doCall() method to specify the parameters in order to call the closure in the short form"